# How to make ScrollView's content transparent

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, uiview, uiscrollview

In Interface Builder I have this hierarchy:

1. View

   1.1 Image View //it's my background

   1.2 Scroll View

   1.2.1 Image View (added as subview to ScrollView above) //here I have image with transparent background

What I'm trying to achieve is to see my background image behind scrollview's image. Now it doesnt work - background of scrollview is black and I don't see background. I was trying with setting off opaque but it didn't help. I have set background on every control to "clear color". I'm out of ideas. Anybody knows how to set values on every element?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Set the background colour of the scrollview to clear. Either via Interface Builder or in code...

```
[myScrollView setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];
```

Comment: Presumably set `myScrollView.opaque = NO;` too, just to be safe? Otherwise the compositor may deal with the scroll view incorrectly.

Comment: yeah, I did set background to clearColor in Interface Builder, but silly me I had set background in code to black, it works now

Answer (score 0):

i solved my problem with this;

in my subview class viewDidload

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view from its nib.
    self.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
    image.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
}
```